# How to only select the very next string after target string but the next string after the target string, regardless of punctation?

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas

I have a df that looks like this:

```
id        query
1         select * from table1 where col1 = 1
2         select a.columns FROM table2 a
```

I want to only select the string (table if you know sql) after the string `FROM` into a new column. `FROM` can be spelled with different capitalizations (ie `From, from,FROM,etc`).

How do I select the string directly after the `From` but not the very next string after the `FROM` string

I tried:

```
df['tableName'] = df['query'].str.extract('[^from]*$')
```

but this is not working. I am not sure if I should make the entire df lowercase right off the bat.

New df should look like this:

```
id        query                                 tableName      
1         select * from table1 where col1 = 1   table1
2         select a.columns FROM table2 a        table2
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```py
df['tableName'] = df['query'].str.extract('(?i)from ([^ ]*)')
```

`(?i)` means ignore case.

```
print(df)

   id                                query tableName
0   1  select * from table1 where col1 = 1    table1
1   2       select a.columns FROM table2 a    table2
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you your answer without a regex and should account for all capitalizations types of "table"

```
df['Table_Name'] = df['query'].apply(lambda x : x.lower().split('from')[1]).apply(lambda x : x.split()[0])
```

Comment: I get `IndexError: list index out of range`, would you know what to do?

Comment: I would need more data, because when I run it against the provided examples it works correctly.